# No transfer value of global variable from block of annonymus function javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, three.js, physijs

I got piece of javascript code:

```
       ... var loaderC = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
        var tes =["first"];
        loaderC.load("computer.json", function (obj) {
            scene.add(obj);  // this is Phisisjs object and it transfer obj properly

            tes.push( 'second');  // inside function  tes got ["first" , "second"]
            console.log("inside anonymous" ); // wont send anything to console
        });
          console.log(tes); // here tes consist only element "first"
```

Looks for me that inside this anonymous function global variables are only coped to another variables and after function is finished all copies are disposed. 
How I can transfer value of variables and object outside of this anonymous function?

Comment: Nothing to do with scope. Everything to do with timing.

Comment: That's right - I checked it again under this point of view and everything is ok.